# Are variables in iterators in PHP global?

Tags: php, variables, scope

I have thought about this for a while. $s1 is set in a foreach loop and can access after the loop, meanwhile $s2 is set in a function say and can't access after because it is local variable. My question is: Are variables in iterators consider global?

```
 <?php
    $systems =  array('windows', 'mac', 'linux');

    foreach ($systems as $s) {
        $s1 = $systems[0];
    }

    echo $s1 . '<br />'; // Echo out "windows"

    function say(){
        $s2 = 'skynet';
        echo $s2;
    }

    say(); // Echo out "skynet"

    echo $s2; // Undefined variable

    ?>
```

Comment: PHP only has two types of scopes: the global scope and function scope. So variables are either in a function or they are global.

Comment: `foreach` is not _an iterator_, it's just a loop statement of the language. Since PHP does not do block level scoping of variables, any variable created in a loop will be accessible after the loop too.

Comment: No, they arent. You cant access $s from outside the foreach loop. However, you can access variables which you create inside a loop.

Comment: ^ ummm ... yes you can, in that instance echoing `$s` after the loop will output "linux".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about information readily available in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 1):

In php there are two types of variables:

- function variables
- global variables

Comment: And in English, there are two kinds of words: written words and spoken words.

Answer (score 1):

No, in your context `$s1` is not global, it simply is at the same level as your print line. Otherwise your `$s2` var is private and exists only inside the `say()` function.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an iterator, such as `foreach()`, then the code will be executed at runtime.

When you declare a `function()`, the code is not executed at runtime. It will only be run through when you call the function.

This is why `$1` is defined, but `$2` is not.

Variables in functions (or class methods) are always local.

Comment: So, do the var $s1 considered global, because it is set in run time and can be access in other files if included. Right?

Comment: Yeah somehow. `$s1` is not defined in a function or a class method, thus it is not local but global.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare `global $s1;`, then $s1 is global. Otherwise, it is not global. If it is not global, then it is accessible only from the same scope where it is defined. In simple terms, if you write `$x=1`, then you can get the value of `$x` from anywhere except inside functions, until the function you defined it in ends.

All your answers are here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php